# navbar-brand image overlapping nav-items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the navbar below, but right now, when I open the page on the browser, the items inside `ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"` are not displayed entirely because are placed behind the navbar-brand image. Anyone knows how to fix that?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand pr-3" href="#">
    <img th:src="@{/img/banner.jpg}" class="d-inline-block align-top pl-3" alt="Kleber App Store">
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pl-3" id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**css for this page**

```
body {
  min-height: 75rem;
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Where you want this image to be?

Comment: the image is the brand of the site. should be at left corner, followed by the links of the navbar to its right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the class and also you dont need position absolute on your CSS file. This action will adjust your image to your layout, trusting you are working with bootstrap, I have removed as well your th:src since it is not necessary as well, check this code below.

```
<img src="@{/img/banner.jpg}" class="d-inline-block align-top pl-3 img-fluid" alt="Kleber App Store">
```

By adding to your class img-fluid, your image will adjust to any screen or layout and fit only where it belongs, make sure that image is not that big too and remove the position from your CSS.